# How to see Mercurial commands issued by Tortoise HG?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I there a way to see what Mercurial commands are issued by Tortoise HG? For instance, if I use the Shelve command in Tortoise, I'd like to see how (and if) it calls 'hg shelve' under the hood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some tools, there's a "View->Always Show Output" option.  It causes commands to run in a console window.  Though often the displayed command line is truncated because it could contain passwords.

TortoiseHg uses Mercurial at multiple API layers, so there's no universal place to get all the commands it issues.  But a couple print statements could get you pretty far.

tortoisehg/hgtk/hgcmd.py - in CmdRunner::execute(), print cmdline
tortoisehg/util/hglib.py - in hgcmd_toq(), print args

To see print statements, you typically have to set THGDEBUG in your environment, and run hgtk with the --nofork option.

Shelve in particular is difficult to intercept, because nearly all of that code is internal to TortoiseHg.  We have a local copy of the shelve extension and call into it directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can only see the `stderr` if some command trigger a problem, [by activating `DEBUG_THG`](http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/stable/wiki/developers/Debugging).

But as far as I know, there is [no command log for TortoiseHg](http://osdir.com/ml/version-control.mercurial.tortoisehg.user/2008-09/msg00008.html).

<sup>And [TortoiseGit is not very strong on this feature either](http://groups.google.com/group/tortoisegit-users/browse_thread/thread/9babc31cfa403a03).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure [Steve Borho's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2609348/3195477) is spot on but there is another simpler approach which might be 90% of what is needed in many cases:

TortoiseHG has a "log" view which can be activated with this toolbar button: [image].

It will show many hg commands as they are run, including their output.

This is the same as the View menu / Show Log option (or `^L`).