# hg equivalent of git add -p?

Tags: git, mercurial, git-add

Is there a mercurial equivalent of `git add -p`?

Quoting from man, git-add with the option -p (or --patch) does the following:

> Interactively choose hunks of patch between the index and the work
>   tree and add them to the index. This gives the user a chance to
>   review the difference before adding modified contents to the index.

Comment: This was at least part of TortoiseHg before the new port, and is currently not implemented in the new port. See https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issue/188/what-happened-to-change-selection-in-the

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: The shelve feature is still available in the latest TortoiseHg.  It can be accessed via the `Repository -> Shelve` menu or through an icon in the commit window.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mercurial cherry picking changes for commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854930/mercurial-cherry-picking-changes-for-commit)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Have a look at the [record extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RecordExtension) (which comes bundled with Mercurial).

Note that since Mercurial doesn't have the concept of the staging area like git, running `hg record` will simply allow you to examine, hunk by hunk, the modifications in your working copy.  Any changes you choose to record will be committed, and any changes you choose *not* to record are simply left as modifications in your working copy.

Comment: "This extensions is deprecated, the feature is now part of Mercurial core as hg commit --interactive."

Comment: This answer is no more relevant nowadays, use `hg commit --interactive`

Answer (score 26):

The [Record Extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RecordExtension) is the standard tool for this. It allows you to pick hunks to include or not in a commit. Once you've enabled the extension in your hgrc, the command is just

```
hg record
```

The [CRecord Extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CrecordExtension) gives you a TUI (Text User Interface) on top of this which allows you to go down to which lines you want to include. This isn't standard though, so it need downloading to a directory before you can enable it in your hgrc.

```
hg crecord
```

---

Edit:

1. The Record extension is no longer necessary since [approx v3.4](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/annotate/3.4/mercurial/commands.py#l1420). Now various commands support
     the `-i` or `--interactive` flag. For example:

   ```
   hg commit -i
   ```

   ...will ask you hunk by hunk what you want to include.
2. CRecord made it in to 3.8 as a core feature. Add the following to your 
     `.hgrc`

   ```
   [ui]
   interface = curses
   ```

   Now, `--interactive` commands will bring up the same interface as the old 
     CRecord extension.

Answer (score 22):

As of Mercurial 3.8.1 the crecord extension is builtin. Make sure the “ui” section in your `.hgrc` contains `interface = curses`, or you get an uncomfortable question-and-answer-interface.

```
[ui]
interface = curses
```

Then do your commits interactively to be asked about which hunk—or—which line you want to include in that commit.

```
hg commit --interactive
```

Comment: Does the question-and-answer interface let you drop down to edit the diff in an editor, like `e` does in `git add -p`?

Answer (score 8):

If you are using TortoiseHg, it has a `Shelve` feature which allows you to store changes you don't want to commit to a temporary area.  It allows hunk selection, just like git.

In the TortoiseHg Workbench, this tool can be accessed in 2 ways:

1. Click `Repository -> Shelve`
2. In `Commit` window, select the shelve tool icon.  It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: The advantage of the shelve approach is that you can test your changes before committing.

Comment: +1 Laurens, It's always bugged me that when doing a 'git add -p', I'm essentially guessing what subset of changes will form a working commit, and then inputing that guess using an error-prone manual process. Asking for trouble.