# Is there an hg equivalent of `git stash save -p` that can split chunks into smaller chunks?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I want to commit only some of the modifications I made to my files and my preferred way to do this is to shelve/stash away the changes I don't want to commit. This allows me to test the changes I will commit before actually commiting them.

The problem I am having is that when I use the "shelve" tool in tortoisehg I can't find any way to split a chunk into two smaller chunks. For example, I have a chunk that looks like this:

```
@@ -1,1 +1,2 @@
-hallo world
+hello world
+something else
```

I would like to shelve away the "something else" so I can commit just the "hallo->hello" fix. However, since tortoisehg is seeing this a single chunk I can either shelve both or none of the changes.

I also tried using the shelve extension via the command line but from what I understood from the documentation it does not offer the feature to shelve away only parts of the files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can accomplish your goal from the command line. There are interactive versions of `hg commit`, `hg revert`, and `hg shelve`, and they have low-level options to hack a patch together if needed; you can use them with the `-i` (or `--interactive`) command line option.

This means that you can build up a commit with `hg commit -i` and `hg commit --amend -i`. If you have the evolve extension installed, you can use `hg uncommit` to pull changes out of the commit again; if not, you can use `hg revert -r .~1` or `hg revert -i -r .~1` a file and use `hg commit --amend -i` again to fix it up.

In order to select individual lines from a patch, you have two options. You can use `e` to edit the patch (but see below for a more convenient option).

You can then use `hg shelve` to shelve the remaining changes.

---

You can in principle also do this with `hg shelve -i`, however, there's a big caveat; if you edit patches for `hg shelve -i`, then Mercurial's merge mechanism will get confused and not process the change cleanly, but dump you in a merge tool in order to resolve this apparent conflict (which means lots of extra work to resolve it). Hence why I strongly recommend using `hg commit -i` and `hg commit --amend -i` if you want to manipulate things at the line level (`hg shelve -i` works fine if you don't edit the patches).

---

For added convenience (that prevents you from editing patches), you can also enable the experimental crecord option by adding the following to your `hgrc` file:

```
[experimental]
crecord = true
```

This will enable a terminal-based hunk editor for `hg commit -i`, `hg revert -i`, and `hg shelve -i` that allows you to select individual lines and hunks (internally, that works roughly the same way as editing patches). Use the `?` key to get help in that editor; use `f` to unfold/fold individual hunks and the space key to select hunks/lines.

Note that line-based selection for this tool in conjunction with `hg shelve -i` comes with the same caveats as editing patches; i.e. use `hg commit -i` and `hg commit --amend -i` instead if you want to do line-based selection. Also, line-based selection for `hg revert -i` will still revert the entire hunk. (There's a reason why this option is still marked as experimental.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a command to do this, but if you are using tortoiseHg, you can do that by selecting modified sections (checkboxes) in the commit preview area.

See [Mercurial cherry picking changes for commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854930/mercurial-cherry-picking-changes-for-commit)

Comment: The problem I have is that there is a single checkbox and that chunk contains both of the changes. How do I turn one checkbox into two checkboxes?